# Is var more resource intensive than explicitly typed variables?

Tags: c#, variables, resources, var

So me and some of my peers at work are looking into the usage of var and why we should/shouldn't use it.

I was wondering if var is more resource intensive than an explicitly typed variable ?

By my understanding it is just a VERY dynamic variable and would (act the same /use the same amount of resources) as any other explicitly typed variable of the type that was passed on to the var.

Could one with more knowledge on the subject please elaborate ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: nope is not, is only sugar-syntax for developers..

Comment: `var` is not dynamic. At compile type the type of the variable is determined. No extra resources are consumed at runtime.

Comment: In most cases var is compiled to the specific type anyway so no it's not more resource intensive

Comment: var just seems lazy in a properly typed language, I try and avoid it, but, realistically I believe its just a simple preference thing.

Comment: @YacoubMassad by dynamic i mean, the type you pass on to it is the type it is...so if i pass on var foo = bar(); ....bar could litterally be anything

Comment: Why should you use it? Do you really want to type `Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()`? `var` improves readability in that case. (but it shouldn't be overused either; for example, don't replace `int i` with `var i`)

Comment: There *is* a dynamic type in c#, which is indicated by the `dynamic` keyword. It is completely different from `var`. Don't confuse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Var is just syntax sugar for explicitly writing out the type.  It saves you some typing and also means that if you change the assigning type then you do not need to update your variable declaration.

For example if you have the following code:

```
        var s = "My String";

        String t = "My String";
```

And then decompile it using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) the fact that `s` was originally declared as `var` is lost.  When the compiler generates the IL it realises that the variable s is a string so replaces `var` with `String`.

Comment: Does the fact that it has to Determine that "s" is  indeed a string not cost resources on startup and thus lengthens the time for the program to start ?

Comment: No. `var` is **NOT** dynamic typing. It is implicit **STATIC** typing. Just like in any other language with implicit static typing, whether that be ML, Haskell, Scala, C++, Kotlin, Ceylon, Rust, Swift, Java, and the myriad other languages. *Nothing* happens at runtime. In languages with powerful whole-program type inference with unification and backtracking, it *may* slow down the *compile* time, but C♯'s type inference is so basic and trivial that its impact is unnoticeable. The compiler has to compute the type of the RHS anyway to check whether the assignment is legal.

Comment: @chimchillas nope it does not have an impact on startup time.  In fact the variable "s" is indeed a string, it is just that you said "var" so you let the compiler figure that out for you at compile time.  Runtime speed is exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

The strong-typing of implicitly typed local variables is determined at compile time and therefore causes zero impact to the performance of your application at runtime.

The `var` keyword simplifies the task of a developer having to type full object names in the variable declaration, and nothing else.

> It is important to understand that the var keyword does not mean "variant" and does not indicate that the variable is loosely typed, or late-bound. It just means that the compiler determines and assigns the most appropriate type.
>   - [Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var stringImplicit = "Blah";
            string stringExplicit = "Blah";

            Console.WriteLine("IMPLICIT : {0} - {1}", stringImplicit, stringImplicit.GetType().Name);
            Console.WriteLine("EXPLICIT : {0} - {1}", stringExplicit, stringExplicit.GetType().Name);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see they become the same regardless. If you looked at the IL (Intermediate Language - compiled code) you would see exactly the same "bytecode". All you are doing is asking the compiler to work it out. This 'effort' of working out the type is no longer present once the compilation has taken place.